# TestRail: how can I create a separate test plan from tests that failed during some test plan execution?

Tags: testrail

I have created a test plan consisting of some number of test cases. The QA has executed this plan. The results are in TestRail and I see that some tests were skipped and some tests failed. What I want is to create a special test plan to account for the tests that were not successfull during this particular execution. I dont want successful tests to be included in that plan and I dont want to do it manually.

Is there some routine in TestRail for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use API from [gurock documentation](http://docs.gurock.com/testrail-api2/start) and to do following:

1. read testRun which is active, read all testcases from it,

[image]

2. from above response catch all failing tests, store it in some collection (List, Map),

   - read this field **"status_id": 2,** status should be 2 = failed
3. create new testRun, and fill it with failed testcases,

[image]

You add Your failed testcases in field "case_ids": [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8],

Hope this helps,